# VersionOne defect status changes

Tags: versionone

I'm trying to find some stats about defects in version one but the reporting and API are getting the type of data I need.

I'm trying to find how long defects sat in a "ready" status and how long defect took to move from "developing" to "testing". I also only want to get it for a subset of the team so I can compare individual developers. I've been trying to get the history of changes for defects but I'm not about to find the detail status.

```
v1.Scope.where(Name='My Project')
v.first().Workitems[0].History[0].ChangedBy.Name
v.first().Workitems[0].History[0].ChangeDateUTC
// need details status
```

Is there any way to get the status change so i can compare the difference between dates? Would this be easier in the reporting tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a predefined [attribute](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Attribute) for status changes. Therefore, the time-in-status value must be calculated using the [attribute definition syntax](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Attribute_Definition_Syntax). We can use the `History` attribute, filtered by the status of interest, and sum up the days. For example, to calculate the time in `Ready`:

```
History[Status.Name='Ready'].Days.@Sum
```

When you say you want to calculate the time it took to move from `Developing` to `Testing`, I assume you mean there is something like `Ready for Test` (if not, then the answer is just like the above only using `Developing` as the filter). The following shows the cycle time across multiple statuses (don't include the end status of `Testing` or you get how long it stayed there too):

```
History[Status.Name='Developing','Ready for Test'].Days.@Sum
```

You can use the [query.v1 endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) to POST the following query:

```
from: Defect
where:
  Scope.Name: My Project
select:
  - Name
  - Status
  - ChangeDateUTC
  - ChangedBy.Name
  - History[Status.Name='Ready'].Days.@Sum
```

Or, using the [rest-1.v1/Data endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData), you can GET the following query (newlines added for readability):

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect
    ?where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='My%20Project'
    &sel=Name,Status,ChangeDateUTC,ChangedBy.Name,History[Status.Name='Ready'].Days.@Sum
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax  you posted. Is it from Python.SDK?